# awk - streamline this script

Tags: awk

I have a text file. On odd number lines, it gives new dimensions of key elements of a building that I'm constructing.

On even number lines, the old dimensions are given.

My aim is to process this file and output for each element the difference. Basically, it means subtracting old from new values. I'd like to do this with awk because I'm interested to do so.

Here's a typical pair of lines from the text file which has 4 columns:

```
groundwall-rvsd 0.0     21.8    0.00
groundwall-orig 0.0     20.2    0.00
```

Here's the script I've put together. It's done the work I need to do but it feels like a clunker.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}
{if(NR%2==1){foo[NR]=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4}else{bar[NR]=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4}} END 
{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){if(i%2==1){split(foo[i], foosplit, OFS );split(bar[i+1], barsplit, OFS);split(foosplit[1], elemt, "-"); 
print elemt[1] OFS foosplit[2] - barsplit[2] OFS foosplit[3] - barsplit[3] OFS foosplit[4] - barsplit[4]}}}' file.txt
```

Any suggestions about a better solution?

The output looks like this

```
groundwall  0   1.6 0
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: i've edited my post to answer your question

Comment: The first step is to put one instruction per line and indent each line. It'll look a lot less clunky that way. What you have now is an unreadable mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} 
    {a[NR]=$2; b[NR]=$3; c[NR]=$4} 
    NR%2 == 0 {
        sub(/-orig$/, "", $1)
        print $1, a[NR]-a[NR-1], b[NR]-b[NR-1], c[NR]-c[NR-1]
    }
' file.txt
```

- use separate arrays to hold the values, so you don't have to do all that splitting
- do your printing on each even-numbered line instead of in the END block

Looking again, you don't even need an array, just remember the values from the previous line:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} 
    NR%2 == 0 {
        sub(/-orig$/, "", $1)
        print $1, a-$2, b-$3, c-$4
    }
    {a = $2; b = $3; c = $4} 
' file.txt
```

Comment: Nice. Just what I wanted - briefer, less fussy, less galumphing, and an alternative construction of a solution to the same problem. Question: doesn't the population of arrays a, b, and c have to be finished off with an END ?

Comment: Your solution doesn't require the array population process to run through the whole input first. V nice. Are the subtractions back to front i.e a[NR-1] - a[NR] is right ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, the subtraction is backwards